# how to combine two arrays into multiple rows in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays

```
array1=[1,2,3]

array2=['one','two','three']
```

I want the result to be

```
res=[[1,'one'],[2,'two'],[3,'three']]
```

[end of problem] The below line was added just to meet the question posting rules:

I tried looking it up online but did not find anything, I can do it in python,but still a beginner in javascript

Answer (score 2):

you can use `array.map` ... one of many ways though :)

```js
const array1=[1,2,3]

const array2=['one','two','three']

const res = array1.map((el,idx)=> [el,array2[idx]])

console.log(res)
```